# probability event was performed by specific group

Tags: probability

Toys for boys and for girls are donated to a benefit event by two groups. The Lakeville Do-Gooders donated 5 toys for boys and 7 for girls. The Southside Champions Club donated 6 toys for boys and 5 for girls. The master of ceremonies pulls the first toy out of a bin and it’s a toy for a boy. Find the probability that it was donated by the Do-Gooders.

-- My thought process is that the sample space is 11 (total number of boy toys [ha]), and there are 5 instances where those eleven toys were donated by the Do-Gooders, making the solution: 5/11. However, given the nature of this class, I'm quite certain this problem can not be asking something so straight forward. Are there other factors I need to be considering?

Comment: I was just wondering about this too. Check out http://toughstem.com/problem-answer-solution/2704/toys-boys-girls-donated-benefit-event-two-lakeville-gooders-donated-toys-boys Its this question answered. You're looking for the probability of P(DG|B) which concludes to the intuitive answer of 5/11.